# codeigniter Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_pconnect() in linux codeigniter

Tags: linux, codeigniter, centos, centos7

Please help. I got this error and I don't know how to fix it.

I'am googling but still no luck. Hope some one can solve this error for me.

I use Codeigniter, postgre in centos 7.

This Is the error:-

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_pconnect()

This is The Full Error

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /var/www/html/mkt/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php:92 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/mkt/system/database/DB_driver.php(116): CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect() #1 /var/www/html/mkt/system/database/DB.php(149): CI_DB_driver->initialize() #2 /var/www/html/mkt/system/core/Loader.php(347): DB(Array, NULL) #3 /var/www/html/mkt/system/core/Loader.php(1172): CI_Loader->database() #4 /var/www/html/mkt/system/core/Loader.php(153): CI_Loader->_ci_autoloader() #5 /var/www/html/mkt/system/core/Controller.php(52): CI_Loader->initialize() #6 /var/www/html/mkt/application/controllers/report.php(9): CI_Controller->__construct() #7 /var/www/html/mkt/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(309): Report->__construct() #8 /var/www/html/mkt/index.php(203): require_once('/var/www/html/m...') #9 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/mkt/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php on line 92

Thank you so much for any help.

Regards,

Dian

Comment: did you enable pgsql extension in php.ini

Comment: no I can't find pgsql extension in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

First of all do this, search in /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini then find this line and uncomment

```
extension="pgsql.so"
```

If the problem is not solved than do this:

The problem is PHP is looking for extensions in the EXTENSIONS directory but... here it comes... "THEY CHANGED THE EXTENSIONS TO DIR MODULES!

Ok so, the workarround is:

```
$ su -
Password:
# ln -s /usr/lib/php/modules  /usr/lib/php/extensions
```

And then edit your /etc/php/php.ini and change the extension_dir to "/usr/lib/php/extensions/"
That's it, this is for every extension that doesn't work (I've tryed uncomment others with the same result until i did this)

Comment: Hi anand , Thanks for reply. I can't find folder php in /usr/lib, i found php.d folder but there's no modules folder nor extensions. please advise. Thanks

Comment: sorry .. but i can't find the folders .. any idea?

Comment: what are you using lampp or xampp ?

Comment: I am not install Lamp nor Xamp. only php and apache httpd

Comment: Hi Anand, I've found the root of problem. it's because I build codeigniter on Php 5, and in my server I install php 7. from what I've read there are deprecated feature on php 7, and my issue is on database driver , I just change the database driver mysql into mysqli. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Ok dian glad to help you